# Build times increase substantially when switching to Java 7

Tags: java, performance, build

We use Java within our build process, as it is used to resolve/publish our dependencies via Ivy.

No problem, nor have we had with it for 2 years, until we've tried to upgrade Java 6 Update 26 to Version 7 Update 7, whereas a build on a local developer PC (WinXP) now takes 2 hours to complete, instead of 10 minutes!!

Nothing else has changed on the PC, making it the absolute target for our concerns.

Does anyone know of any reason as to why version 7 of Java would make such a speed difference like this?

UPDATE: The build process is NAnt-based, so Java.exe is called from a NAnt script, running in a Command (DOS) window.

Comment: How are you building your application ? Do you use a script ? An IDE ?

Comment: Some optimisations were turned of in Java 7. Can you try Java 6 update 35 as this is more similar to Java 7 update 7?

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is interesting. Do you have references about the compilation time problem in java7 ?

Comment: Java 6, update 35 was what I ended up running to get the speed back to a 'normal' level (had to uninstall 7 update 7 as well) (It was on my machine it was taking 2 hours...)

Comment: I know that some optimisations were added and some were removed by default. I haven't seen this impact compilation time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ideally, we'd stay on version 6 if only for the speed thing, but our tech guys are pushing us to get 7 installed due to the fixed vulnerabilities present in 6.

Comment: @Brett, the version of the JRE installed for security reasons shouldn't affect the version of the JDK you use to build your application. You can have JRE 7 installed (and set up to run applets with, etc) but still build with 6. The IT security concerns for your desktops shouldn't influence decisions on how to build the source code - these are orthogonal.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler to see where it's using up most of the time? Is it in `javac` or is it in ivy somewhere?

Comment: Running some test compiling with Java 6 vs 7 on Windows 7 64-bit and I can't see much difference.

Comment: While your (long) build is running, you can do 2 things to get an idea on what's happening, using commands that come with the JDK: `jstat -gc PID 5s 12` will give you the memory occupancy and GC counts every 5 seconds for one minute (to see if for some reason, you're almost hitting the maximum heap size and garbage-collecting continuously), `jstack PID` will give you a thread dump, which you can do a few times repeatedly (to see if it's for example hung on some network connection, unrelated to your JDK upgrade). Update your question if you need help reading the results.

Comment: Are both JDKs the same bit-ness? (both 32bit or both 64bit?)

Comment: Any chance all the code (most of it?) is also in an IDE?  If so, can you install a Java 7 there and let it do a clean and build - how long does that take?  FWIW, we use Java 7 exclusively and switched from Java 6 without any noticeable performance hit.

Comment: This may be a long shot but have you tried adding all of your build tools to your AntiVirus ignore list? I often find that my Visual Studio builds take 10-20x as long before I configure AV settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Java 7 was a huge step backward in terms of speed and compatibility.  I've found it slower not only to compile, but running the JRE as well.

I've also had major issues running eclipse with it (and yes, i've used update 7).

And from my standpoint there's nothing in Java 7 that i need.  I like the ForkJoinPool, and can get that as an add on library for Java 6.

Maybe Java 8 will be better.

Comment: He said the build went from 10 minutes to 120 minutes (2 hours). That's a factor of 12 increase in time. Nant is a .NET tool, anyway, so surely a lot of the runtime is not even Java related. So that makes the factor an increase of incredibly greater magnitude. I would be shocked to hear that the Java engineering team did something that increases runtime by 100 times plus. I conclude therefore this is very likely something else besides the JVM.

Comment: I did indeed say that the builds now took 120 mins to run, which is devastating. But the **only** thing I had upgraded was the JDK, which I can only feel is responsible for the difference in speed.

Comment: Does the Java comprise 10 percent of the build or 100 percent (unlikely, I think, since Nant is used)? My point is that 1 min of Java work in the 10 minute build would now account for 111 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I guess those numbers wouldn't be too far away from the truth.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JDK 7u7 and I noticed a better performance by tuning some [VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

You could try the G1GC and AgressiveOpts to help with compile time.

Follow the settings I use in my editor:

```
-Xss8m 
-Xmn256m 
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:+UseG1GC 
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat 
-XX:+UseStringCache 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
```

You will find each option's description in the [VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) link.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, did you remove JDK6 or leave it in place? Check your JDK_HOME and any other place it is specified to ensure that you are actually using JDK7. In the XP console type `java -version` and ensure it is what is expected. (Close/reopen the command prompt to pick up changes in the Win GUI.)

It was never stated what version of XP you are running -- 64-bit or 32-bit. Ensure the appropriate JDK environment is on the machine. (Depending on exactly what is executing, this can make a tangible difference. Also, the best bet for debugging is to keep it the same as before -- reduce variables.)

Troubleshoot the issue and narrow it down. Does an Eclipse installation perform slower after the upgrade? (Eclipse itself runs in a JVM. It's a good baseline.) Is Eclipse pointing at the correct JDK when you test it? Try other Java tools to see if there is a performance difference. Breakpoints and logging at different control points in the build and any Java executables are your friends.

Since [Nant is .NET based](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/introduction/fog0000000006.html), have you looked at the Java process that is actually launched? Is your Ivy distribution really old?

All this said, it is hard for me to believe this is a Java issue and not a configuration challenge on the Windows box. Have you tried it on any other machines, anyway?

Comment: Its Windows XP Pro, 32 bit. We've had zero speed problems until we upgraded to version 7 and then it slowed down dramatically. I've even checked the version of the Ivy distrib that we're using (v2.1.0), and even the latest (v2.3.0) makes no difference.  And yes, I had totally removed v6 of the JDK and all references to it when I upgraded to 7.

Comment: Also, as we don't use Eclipse, so I wouldn't be able to compare speeds before/after the upgrade to v7 of Java.

Comment: Were there any jars in the JDK6 lib directory that failed to get moved over? What about other environment settings (path)? Nothing pointing to JDK6 directories still? I have seen slowdowns like this but it always ended up something configuration related.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the speed issue on a new Windows 7 PC (i.e. one that has not ever had a version of Java installed) and the 7u7 version makes it run slow.

Comment: Oracle's release notes for JDK7 noted significant performance improvements, and a speed benchmark for JDK versions at http://geeknizer.com/java-7-whats-new-performance-benchmark-1-5-1-6-1-7/ indicates it's much faster. I am not disputing your observations, of course the speed of your use case has been observed.

Comment: What about the Java process' memory allocation? Can it be increased? Does the machine memory throttle when the Java runs causing VM paging usage? If you can test different Xms/Xmx settings it might help.